# OpenCV python object detection code error

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I keep recieving error messages and I am running out of effort to fix it. Any help? I feel like im running in circles because it keeps telling me that there is an index error. Here is the error message:

```
PS C:\Users\dmmal\OneDrive\CS110\ObjectDetector> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dmmal\OneDrive\CS110\ObjectDetector\main.py", line 32, in <module>
    x, y, w, h = bbox[ind[0]]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

thres = 0.45  # Threshold to detect object
nms_threshold = 0.2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

classNames = []
classFile = 'labels.txt'
with open(classFile,'rt') as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')

configPath = 'ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt'
frozen_model = 'frozen_inference_graph.pb'

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(frozen_model, configPath)
net.setInputSize(320, 320)
net.setInputScale(1.0 / 127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img, confThreshold=thres)
    bbox = list(bbox)
    confs = list(np.array(confs).reshape(1, -1)[0])
    confs = list(map(float, confs))

    indices = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(bbox, confs, thres, nms_threshold)
    if len(classIds) > 0:
        for ind in indices:
            x, y, w, h = bbox[ind[0]]
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
            cv2.putText(img, classNames[classIds[ind[0]] - 1].upper(), (x + 10, y + 30),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Output", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I tried changing it many different ways but nothing seems to work. Could use some help.

Comment: The error means that `ind` is a single value; it cannot be indexed.  Why are you trying to index it?  What value did you expect `ind` to be?